# What type to use for props of a wrapped Bootstrap component in a stateless function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to encapsulate a [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io) component in a stateless function:

```js
import React from "react"
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap"

export function MyComponent(props: ???) {
  const { children, ...otherProps } = props;
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Body {...otherProps}>{children}</Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

My question: **what props should I use for `???`?**

I've tried pulling out bits of the [React Bootstrap type definition](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/types/components/Card.d.ts#L15) to end up with this:

```js
export function MyComponent<As extends React.ElementType = 'div'>(props: ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>) {
  const { children, ...otherProps } = props;
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Body {...otherProps}>{children}</Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

But this gives the following monster error message:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>>): CardBody<As>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Pick<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>, "as" | "bsPrefix" | Exclude<Exclude<keyof ComponentPropsWithRef<As>, "as" | "bsPrefix">, "children">> & { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<CardBody<As>> & Readonly<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>> & Readonly<...>'.
      Type 'Pick<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>, "as" | "bsPrefix" | Exclude<Exclude<keyof ComponentPropsWithRef<As>, "as" | "bsPrefix">, "children">> & { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>, context?: any): CardBody<As>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Pick<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>, "as" | "bsPrefix" | Exclude<Exclude<keyof ComponentPropsWithRef<As>, "as" | "bsPrefix">, "children">> & { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<CardBody<As>> & Readonly<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>> & Readonly<...>'.
      Type 'Pick<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>, "as" | "bsPrefix" | Exclude<Exclude<keyof ComponentPropsWithRef<As>, "as" | "bsPrefix">, "children">> & { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As>>>'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too versed in utilizing typescript but from what it looks like, you could use the following to allow the optional props.

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";

type CardContainerProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  as?: React.ElementType;
  bsPrefix?: string;
}

export function MyComponent({ children, ...otherProps }: CardContainerProps) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Body {...otherProps}>{children}</Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps!